# How to resolve eslint "Generic Object Injection Sink" error?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, eslint

I'm trying to read a JSON array. Every time i try to read the array/value by passing JSON object key like this-

```
json[key]
```

It shows a Eslint error-

```
[eslint] Generic Object Injection Sink (security/detect-object-injection)
```

I understand its a security warning because the key may not exists. But how do i resolve this warning? Is there any easier way to read the Json object. My plan is to pass the "key" to the function and read the json based on the key.

Comment: From the Readme: "This project will help identify potential security hotspots, but finds a lot of false positives which need triage by a human." I read that as "you're not supposed to fix them all".

Comment: Disable this rule then?

Comment: Sometimes it is required, when an outsource (like user input) could be involved. Check @viveksharma 's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55701580

Comment: This post explains why it can be a security issue: https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/blob/master/docs/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation.md

In my opinion, you can `eslint-disable` it when you are (sure you are) not using user input for the `key`

Comment: can anyone help me with a question like this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295517/node-js-generic-object-injection-sink-on-eslint-using-for-iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295517/node-js-generic-object-injection-sink-on-eslint-using-for-iteration)

Answer (score 24):

You are searching for an ES lint error fix:

Here is the syntax for it

```
json [`${key}`]
```

Example:

```js
const obj = { 
    eventName: 'Music event', 
    landingPic: 'landing.jpg',
    eventPic0: 'pic0.jpg',
    eventPic1: 'pic1.jpg',
    eventPic2: 'pic2.jpg',
    eventPic3: 'pic3.jpg',
    artist: 'Elie'
};

// array of keys which need to  be read
const arrayOfKey = ['landingPic', 'eventPic0', 'eventPic1',  'eventPic2',  'eventPic3'];

// let's read the value by a key in array
arrayOfKey.forEach( key => {
    const value = obj[`${key}`];
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: This may fix the ES Lint error, but this is a security issue. Does this help with that issue ???

Comment: Apparently, line '12' (const arrayOfKey ...) is a whilelist of allowed keys. So yes, it helps with the security issue.

Comment: Nice. Also this will convert the value of the key to a string.

Comment: You may as well just use `eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-object-injection` since you are writing code to make it safe. The language hack of converting it using back ticks (`\`${key}\``) is likely a bug in the eslint rule that should be fixed.

Comment: This is clearly not a good way to fix this issue. The security issue is explained here https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-security/blob/main/docs/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation.md

So you should not use back ticks to avoid this rule, it is not making it safer. But in this example, there is no security issue.

You can just disable it, if you concider it noisy

Answer (score 5):

There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64207784/4079915). In general this rule is for paranoiac and [the article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150430062816/https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/15/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation) to which everyone appeal is a mislead. So the best answer, I would say is to turn this rule off, if you can for sure.

And [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295517/node-js-generic-object-injection-sink-on-eslint-using-for-iteration) in the comments refers to [eslint contributor answer](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/issues/21#issuecomment-326031625) that this rule is pretty false positive prone and more for  human to audit a codebase(warning level) rather then give an error in a CI. So I would say you can totally ignore this rule or turn it off.

If you cannot turn it off or ignore, you can disable the eslint for line with comment that it's a false positive or use some interpolation as mentioned in other answers.

And finally, in order to destroy any doubts, the [answer from creator](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/issues/21#issuecomment-1157887653) of the rule:

> *"I'm the original author of this rule - for a bit of context, it was originally written as an assistive tool for manual code reviews, to be
> used with the eslint plugin for VS Code. I would recommend disabling
> it for other use cases, as it's just going to be far too noisy."*

Answer (score 2):

Unsure why, but typecasting the access parameter silences the error. Guessing this has something to do with sanitation being able to prevent pollution.

```
const myThing = myObj[String(key)]
const myThing = myObj[key as string]
```

Answer (score 0):

What its trying to say is that using this notation:

- You are able to modify even prototype properties of the object which is considered dangerous
- By being able to modify everything, you are also able to modify the constructor (method/function) so it may be injected and then exploited.

The subject is described analytically here, providing a simple example:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150430062816/https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/15/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation