# Node.js - Generic Object Injection Sink (on eslint) using FOR iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, code-injection

I have a node project and a function to find a specific object item

My code:

> ```
> const filterObjectItem = (myObject, property, value) => {
>     for (const prop in myObject) {
>         if (prop === property) {
>             for (const item in myObject[prop]) {
>                 if (item === value) {
>                     return myObject[prop][item][0]
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     return false
> }
> ```

the function workingl, but I'm getting this warning when running the eslint

```
warning  Generic Object Injection Sink  security/detect-object-injection
```

does anyone have an idea how to refactor the function to solve this warnning?

Comment: Don't refactor. Ignore or remove the rule. [Issue 21](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/issues/21#issuecomment-326031625): "*We know Object injection is pretty false positive prone*". And it doesn't even do what it advertises ("*Detects variable[key] as a left- or right-hand assignment operand.*") - there is no assignment in your code. It just complains about *every* dynamic member access.