# how to fix codacy alert "Generic Object Injection Sink"

Tags: javascript, codacy

Below is my code. I don't think there is any problem.

How can I fool codacy? If I can't use `obj[key]`, then what the hell is this thing? There is no way I can avoid `[]`.

```
handleClick = (e, titleProps) => {
     const { index } = titleProps
     const newVal = this.state.activeIndexObj[index]? false: true
     let activeIndexObj = {...this.state.activeIndexObj}
     activeIndexObj[index] = newVal
     // Generic Object Injection Sink (security/detect-object-injection)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it bad pratice calling an array index with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882542/why-is-it-bad-pratice-calling-an-array-index-with-a-variable)

Comment: please, keep the comments respectful @NicolasS.Xu

Answer (score 24):

You just need to parse index into integer

```
activeIndexObj[parseInt(index)] = newVal
```

there could be chances hacker may inject function or prototype chaining so that's why this security error comes.

Comment: Your amazing ! Brilliant idea

Comment: Unfortunately this brings a type script error: TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. My index is of type number, but security error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

if it's a number like i here try this :

```
 ranges[`${i}`]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the question linked on the comment by @luca ([Why is it bad pratice calling an array index with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882542/why-is-it-bad-pratice-calling-an-array-index-with-a-variable))  explains the problem with using a variable to access an array index. It's a security question.

If you allow a non validated input to be used as an array index, your application may crash. Even if you validate the index, it's a matter of time until you refactor the code and the validation be skipped. Hence the recommendation to avoid such code. One recommended solution is to use a Map: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44882765/4398050

If you don't wanna know about this problem, it is possible to ignore the issue in the codacy UI: https://support.codacy.com/hc/en-us/articles/207279979-Issues#2-remove-pattern

Comment: The answer in "Why is it bad practice calling an array index with a variable" does not make sense at all. I think the answer is wrong.

Comment: well, in the codacy UI there are links explaining the issue, have a look by yourself: https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security#detect-object-injection