# How can I access an array value without using array[key]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, security

I'm writing a simple code to get the value inside an array. I'm using `array[key]` to get the value stored inside this array, in a `for` loop.

```js
var array = ["Foo", "Bar"];

function getValue() {
  for (var key = 0; key < array.length; key++) {
    console.log(array[value]);
  }
}
```

This method is simple and works fine, however, I've read that this could cause security issue ([The Dangers of Square Bracket Notation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150430062816/https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/15/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation)), and ESlint is not OK with it, throwing this error:

> **Generic Object Injection Sink (security/detect-object-injection)**
>
> Detects variable[key] as a left- or right-hand assignment operand. ([ESLint reference](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security#detect-object-injection))

How can I access the value of the array without using this method ?

I've already read the related question: [Why is it bad pratice calling an array index with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882542/why-is-it-bad-pratice-calling-an-array-index-with-a-variable) and as this question seems too hard to generalize I decided to ask a new canonical question.

Comment: Since you are dealing with Arrays, try `Array.forEach(function(value) { console.log(value)})`. If you can tell what exactly you are doing, we could suggest better

Comment: where is `value` defined?

Comment: @nickzoum `value` is user-defined

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: What exactly is eslint complaining about? Please post the error message. I bet it's about using `for in`, not `array[value]`.

Comment: @Bergi I corrected my code and added the exact error. Is it better to you?

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea what this rule detects exactly, but a generic `…[var]` matching doesn't help with security due to the huge number of false positives. Also, I cannot find the explanation for the rule, the page https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/14/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation/ which is linked from the rule reference seems to be down (has a security warning and no content).

Comment: Btw, `var key = 0;`

Comment: Yeah, I found the page with the internet archive : https://web.archive.org/web/20150430062816/https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/15/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

**First**: You could use `for..of` loop. `for..of` doesn't use the square bracket notation and doesn't give the index directly.

```
for (let element of list) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

**Second**: The other way is what @Rajesh has mentioned: `ForEach`.

```js
list.ForEach((element) => {
  console.log(element)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript offers many method to help you iterate over array for mapping, filtering and only iterating arrays. Look on the few of them:

1. forEach() method

   ```
   let arr = [1,2,3,4,10];
   arr.forEach((item, index) => console.log(item)) //1,2,3,4,10
   ```

   This method also allows you to get index of the item.
2. for-of loop

   ```
   for(item of arr) {
     console.log(item) //1,2,3,4,10
   }
   ```

   This new feature introduced in ES6 and this recommended to iterate over arrays.

   If you want manipulate arrays you can use following method, which also iterating over arrays:
3. filter()

   ```
   arr.filter((item, index)=> item > 5) // Return new array [10]
   ```
4. map()

   ```
   arr.map((item, index)=> item*2) // Return new array [2,4,6,8,20]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.at`.

```
['a','b','c','d','e'].at(2); // 'c'
```